# Natural RE undecidable problems but not Turing-complete

Tags: computability, turing-completeness

The Halting problem is a natural undecidable language which is complete for the set of recursivly enumrable sets. I am interested in undecidable but not Turing-complete language such that we can not reduce the Halting problem to it.

What is the most **natural** undecidable RE problem which is not Turing-complete?

Answer (score 9):

There indeed are sets that are undecidable but not Turing complete.  However,  I'm not sure there is such a thing as a *natural* undecidable not Turing complete language.

Emil Post set out on a search for exactly this (See [Post's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_problem#Post.27s_problem_and_the_priority_method)) and his research resulted in the [Simple sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_set).  To quote from the Wikipedia article:

> [Its existence] was affirmed by Friedberg and Muchnik in the 1950s using a novel technique called the priority method. They give a construction for a set that is simple (and thus non-recursive), but fails to compute the halting problem.

Comment: I will wait for a natural problem.

Comment: Some have argued that there are none.

Comment: Could you provide a pointer?