# A variant of the busy beaver function

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Reading this question "[Natural RE undecidable problems but not Turing-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/natural-re-undecidable-problems-but-not-turing-complete)" the following language came to my mind:

If $\Sigma(\cdot)$ is the busy beaver function (maximum attainable score among all halting 2-symbol n-state Turing machines of the above-described type, when started on a blank tape), define the function:

$$BB(\langle M \rangle) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{$\langle M \rangle$ computes $\Sigma(\cdot)$}\\  
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Now define the language:

$L = \{ \langle M \rangle \; | \; \langle M \rangle \mbox{ halts and } BB(\langle M \rangle) = 0 \}$

> Is $L$ recursively enumerable? (it should be r.e.: just simulate in parallel M with all TMs of the same length, and if $M$ halts and another $M'$ halts with a higher score add M to the enumeration).
>
> Can we reduce the halting problem to $L$ ? (it seems that it cannot "capture" the halting of the busy beavers)

Comment: Is $|\langle M \rangle|$ the number of states?

Comment: When will you enumerate an $M$ that doesn't halt into $L$?  $L$ can't be RE unless you enumerate _all_ its members, and the procedure you've described only enumerates those that actually halt.

Comment: @PålGD: yes it is the number of states (halting state excluded)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I implictly assumed that $L$ contains only machines that halt ... perhaps I should clarify it in the question (let me think about it a little bit, perhaps it makes the question trivial).

Comment: @Vor Yes, it is enumerable for the reason you say.

Comment: As you have currently stated the question, it is indeed trivial: If we have an oracle for $L$, then we have an oracle for $\bar{L}$; but as $\bar{L}$ is the set of busy beavers, this allows us to decide the halting problem.

Comment: The argument for $L$ being r.e. is not correct as others have pointed out: a machine in $L$ doesn't need to halt in the first place. You can consider the promise problem where you don't care about those machines. In any case the question need to be clarified.

Comment: @Kaveh It's not even a promise problem - you can simply define $L$ (as I believe the OP intended) as $L=\{\langle M\rangle | M\ \text{halts} \wedge BB(\langle M\rangle) = 0\}$.

Comment: @Steven, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't see this before — but yes, with an oracle for $L$ you can solve the halting problem.  Obviously an oracle for $L$ gives us 'recursively' all non-Busy Beaver halting machines, so the question is 'can we figure out recursively in $L$ what the busy beavers are?'.  Define $\Sigma_2(n)$ as the count function of the 'second busiest beaver'; that is, the second-highest attainable score among all halting two-symbol $n$-state TMs.  The trick here is that there's a recursive function $f()$ such that $\Sigma(n)\leq\Sigma_2(f(n))$ (it's almost certain that $f(n)=n+1$ will do the trick, in fact, but that requires knowing that the BB function is strictly increasing) : given a machine $M$ of size $n$ that prints $\Sigma(M)$ 1s on its tape and then halts, there's some $c\gt 1$ and two machines each of size $\leq cn$ that print exactly $\Sigma(M)$ 1s and exactly $\Sigma(M)+1$ 1s, respectively, on their tapes — and this holds true for a 'busy beaver' machine $M$ *even though we don't know $M$ explicitly*.  This means that having a bound on the 'second busy beaver' function for $f(n)$ gives a bound for the busy beaver function on $n$; but then having this, it's easy to solve the halting problem for a TM $M$ of size $n$ - if $\langle M\rangle\in L$ then say that $M$ halts; otherwise, find the longest-running machine of size $f(n)$ in $L$ (which can be done recursively since there are only finitely many machines of size $\leq f(n)$) and simulate $M$ for as many steps as that machine takes to halt.  If $M$ doesn't halt within that time then $M$ can't possibly halt.

Comment: Thanks; inspired by your answer I found a quick (trivial )-: direct reduction from the halting problem in a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a reworked version of Steven's good answer, with an explicit reduction from the Halting problem.

Given $\langle M \rangle, w$ build $M'$ that runs $M$ on $w$ and if it halts goes to the right of the tape, writes a 0 and halt.

If $M'$ halts, $BB(M')=0$ because there is an equivalent TM of the same size that writes a 1 and halts; so we can use the decider for $L$ to check if $M$ halts on $w$ ($M$ halts on $w$ iff $M' \in L$)

... it turned out that the question is indeed trivial :-)